# Не работает свой ocmod модификатор opencart 3

Tags: xml, opencart, opencart3.x

Написал свой модификатор. Назвал его install.xml, упаковал в архив mod_name.ocmod.zip. Устанавливаю с помощью стандартного установщика - установка проходит успешно, xml код добавляется в бд. Но никак не хочет работать. Код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<modification>
    <code>add_module_position</code>
    <name>Добавление позиции вывода модулей</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <author>Author</author>
    <link>https://site.ru</link>
    <file path="admin\view\template\design\layout_form.twig">
        <operation>
            <search>
                <![CDATA[<table id="module-content-top" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">]]>
            </search>
            <add position="before">
                <![CDATA[<table id="module-content-new" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">{{ text_content_new }}</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for layout_module in layout_modules %}
    {% if layout_module.position == 'content_new' %}
    <tr id="module-row{{ module_row }}">
        <td class="text-left"><div class="input-group">
                <select name="layout_module[{{ module_row }}][code]" class="form-control input-sm">
                    {% for extension in extensions %}
                    <optgroup label="{{ extension.name }}">
                        {% if not extension.module %}
                        {% if extension.code == layout_module.code %}
                        <option value="{{ extension.code }}" selected="selected">{{ extension.name }}</option>
                        {% else %}
                        <option value="{{ extension.code }}">{{ extension.name }}</option>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% else %}
                        {% for module in extension.module %}
                        {% if module.code == layout_module.code %}
                        <option value="{{ module.code }}" selected="selected">{{ module.name }}</option>
                        {% else %}
                        <option value="{{ module.code }}">{{ module.name }}</option>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    </optgroup>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
                <input type="hidden" name="layout_module[{{ module_row }}][position]" value="{{ layout_module.position }}" />
                <input type="hidden" name="layout_module[{{ module_row }}][sort_order]" value="{{ layout_module.sort_order }}" />
                <div class="input-group-btn"> <a href="{{ layout_module.edit }}" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ button_edit }}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                    <button type="button" onclick="$('#module-row{{ module_row }}').remove();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ button_remove }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div></td>
    </tr>
    {% set module_row = module_row + 1 %}
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-left"><div class="input-group">
                <select class="form-control input-sm">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    {% for extension in extensions %}
                    <optgroup label="{{ extension.name }}">
                        {% if not extension.module %}
                        <option value="{{ extension.code }}">{{ extension.name }}</option>
                        {% else %}
                        {% for module in extension.module %}
                        <option value="{{ module.code }}">{{ module.name }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    </optgroup>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" onclick="addModule('content-new');" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ button_module_add }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div></td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>]]>
            </add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="admin/language/ru-ru/design/layout.php">
        <operation>
            <search>
                <![CDATA[$_['text_content_top']    = 'Верх страницы';]]>
            </search>
            <add position="after">
                <![CDATA[$_['text_content_new'] = 'Меню в шапке';]]>
            </add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

В чем ошибка?

В логе:

```
MOD: Добавление позиции вывода модулей

FILE: admin/language/ru-ru/design/layout.php
CODE: $_['text_content_top']    = 'Верх страницы';
LINE: 14
```

Т.е. для второго файла всё отрабатывает, а для первого нет. Строку в нем проверял (которую ищем) - она точно есть и именно в таком вхождении.

Comment: наверное, почистите кеш

Comment: @ Kirill Korushkin Кэш модификаторов и системы я чистил - это не помогает